# Draw a filled rectangle in Cocos 2d v3

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, xcode5

I want to draw several filled square using `Coco2d v3` where the color is filled programmatically and has a border.

I have tried this code from a post, but it isn't working.  The blank is a transparent 1*1 pixel image .

```
-(CCSprite *) rectangleSpriteWithSize:(CGSize)cgsize color:(CCColor*) c
{
    CCSprite *sg = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"Blank.png"];
    [sg setTextureRect:CGRectMake( 0, 0, cgsize.width, cgsize.height)];

    [sg setColor:c];
    return sg;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try a CCNodeColor :

```
-(CCNode*) rectangleSpriteWithSize:(CGSize)size color:(CCColor*) c {
    CCNodeColor *nc = [CCNodeColor nodeWithColor:c width:size.width height:size.height];
    return nc;
 }
```

Comment: But how to draw the border around the square